# Journalism examples using officials public data portals?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, data-portal

I'm living in Europe. For researches purposes, I'm trying to gather news articles explicitly using data from officials portals as data.gov.uk for instance.

Please consider this, however:

- The data can also come from any data.gov.* portals around the world (such as the UK portal). I'm not specifically asking for US examples ;
- The articles/app doesn't have to be made by journalists, but should have a clear informational purpose ;

Comment: I find it a little confusing that you refer to data.gov, a specific site, but also indicate that you're interested in articles explicitly using "any data.gov portals." I guess there are also data.gov.uk and data.gov.ie and probably others. Also, EveryBlock, for example, doesn't use data from "data.gov" because it focuses at city level. Also its data sources predate the actual "data.gov" site. Maybe you can clarify the question and especially the headline?

Comment: data.gov refers to the US portal. In UK, it's "data.gov.uk", "data.gov.be" in Belgium and so on. 

I cited EveryBlock for the informational purpose of the initiative only. Sorry, I'm lacking of relevant exemples, that's why I'm asking for informations.

Comment: I think what you call a "news article" is actually a [press release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Press_release). I think [this list](https://www.gov.uk/government/announcements?keywords=data&announcement_filter_option=all&topics[]=all&departments[]=department-for-education&world_locations[]=all&from_date=&to_date=) would be a place to start for UK press releases about data.

Comment: When you say 'public data portals' ... do they have to be government run?  I saw a talk at the IDCC (International Digital Curation Conference) last year and someone gave a talk on the reporting of riots in ... the UK, I think it was.  He discussed how they tracked down when & where things were happening via Twitter.  Go to http://www.dcc.ac.uk/events/idcc14/video-gallery and scroll down to the talk by Paul Lewis at the end of Day 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here's one: http://www.theage.com.au/victoria/the-most-ignored-parking-sign-in-melbourne-20140512-zraek.html

Here's the background: http://www.theage.com.au/data-point/blogs/the-crunch--data-point/melbourne-parking--get-the-data-20140513-386wv.html

Summary: data journalists from The Age found data on the City of Melbourne's data portal, wrote a story from it.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few examples of embedded data from open data portals in the USA:

- http://news.yahoo.com/find-out-here-how-much-your-favorite-obama-aide-is-paid-211525283.html embeds data from open.whitehouse.gov
- http://www.nationaljournal.com/tech/how-cispa-opponents-were-outspent-by-industry-lobbyists-38-to-1-20130422 embeds data from data.sunlightlabs.com, a data portal from a non profit/non partisan organization

Comment: Thanks a lot, not quite what I was looking for but still intersting